# Free solvers in C/C++ for convex integer programming

Tags: convex-optimization, math-software, integer-programming

I need to solve the following integer program:

$\text{minimize } \sum_{i=1}^n(a_{i0} x_i + \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik}w_i^k + \sum_{j=1}^m d_{ij}y_{ij})$

$\text{subject to}$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_{ij}=1, \quad j=1,\ldots,m,\\
\sum_{j=1}^m y_{ij}\le m x_i, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,\\
\sum_{j=1}^m y_{ij} b_{ij} \le x_i, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,\\
\sum_{j=1}^m y_{ij} c_{ij} \le w_i, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,\\
w_i \le x_i, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,\\
x_i \in \{0,1\}, \quad i=1,\ldots,n\\
y_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,\; j=1,\ldots,m,\\
w_i \in [0,1], \quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$

where $a_{ik},b_{ij},c_{ij},d_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ are real constants.

Note that, if I'm not wrong, the above problem should be convex since the  second derivative of the objective function is always positive (that is, some coefficient can be negative but the whole sum is guaranteed to be positive).

I know there is the excellent [CVX toolbox](http://cvxr.com/cvx/), but it is MATLAB only.
What I'm looking for is a solver with similar capabilities that has C/C++ API.

Can you suggest anyone?

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look, your problem is LINEAR. This makes a huge difference, since nonlinear mixed integer programming is much more difficult than mixed integer linear programming.

If you are a student you can get academic licenses for [GUROBI](http://www.gurobi.com) or CPLEX. Those are pretty much the best commercial solvers for MILPs. If you want something open source, you can try the COIN-OR project. It provides CBC and SYMPHONY, both MILP solvers which are quite good. If your problem isn't too big you can also try GLPK. There's quite a lot of MILP solvers out there so you can try looking for more on google.

On a side note, your variables are all binary, which makes me think this is a combinatorial problem. If you have good structure, I would try to exploit it and go for a greedy algorithm and see if you can prove optimality or use it as a good heuristic.

EDIT: For mixed integer nonlinear programming COIN-OR provides BONMIN and COUENNE. [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/) also claims to be able to solve MINLPs but not entirely sure if they restrict problems to being quadratic.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is linear? I'm not a mathematician (I'm a computer scientists) so I'm not an expert, but I thought that since the objective function contains a cubic polynomial for variables $w_i$ (which are real variables bounded in the $[0,1]$ real interval) the problem is to be considered as a convex mixed-integer nonlinear problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, segault, your objective function is not linear, wonko's suggestions here won't work for you.

Comment: Ah you're right, didn't notice that. Wasn't reading the model carefully enough. Can you check if you can reformulate this into a linear model? In any case I edited the answer and put in some mixed integer nonlinear solvers.

Comment: I cannot remove the cubic polynomial from the objective and unfortunately I'm not aware of techniques to transform such type of problem into linear one. Do they exist? If they do, can you give me some hint or reference?

Comment: Nothing really pops into my head either. The general line of thought was to try to replace the cubic terms with auxiliary variables and adjust the constraints accordingly, but not sure if that is possible. Anyway try BONMIN and SCIP out and see if it works. Are you restricted to C/C++? And how large is the problem? Can you prototype a small example in AMPL and perhaps try to solve it on NEOS?

Comment: I did not considered Bonmin/Couenne since they are general MINLP solvers. What I'm looking for is something like CVX (see link in my original post) which exploits the convexity of the problem. Indeed, if I'm not wrong, my problem should be convex as the second derivative of objective function is guaranteed to be always positive. Regarding C/C++, yes I'm bounded to it. The size of the problem should be $n \le 500$ and $m \le 800$.

Comment: I think SCIP is your best best. CVX would use MOSEK and Gurobi in this case, but to do so involves translating the cubic polynomial into a mess of second-order cone constraints, which is a hairy process to try to do by hand.

Comment: Maybe, [MOSEK](http://www.mosek.com)? It can handle some kind of [separable convex problem](http://docs.mosek.com/7.0/capi/Separable_convex_optimization.html) which seems to feet with mine.

Comment: Sorry, in the above comment: "feet" -> "fit" :)

Comment: Yes, it has a separable convex solver but I don't think that solver can handle binary or integer variables as well. If it does, by all means, go for it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that integer vars are supported for only certain type of convex programming, like conic quadratic programming, which I think it doesn't fit to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [dlib](http://dlib.net/) - it has some decent routines for general nonlinear optimization that you might be able to adapt to your problem (though on second glance, I'm not sure it handles integer programs directly). I played with it some a while back but it ended up being faster to write my own system.  The best part: it's extremely well documented and written.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something more specific for my problem (convexity + mixed-integer), As @wonko suggested, there are good MINLP solvers, but, if possible, I'm looking for something more specialized (like CVX)